# сохранить встроенные покупки swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, in-app-purchases, nsuserdefaults

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сохранить встроенные покупки, а именно - жизни в игре. 
NSUserDefaults подойдет для этого?

Comment: да, подойдет...

Comment: Я просто слышал, что "NSUserDefaults не защищен, любой может сам себе сколько угодно покупок сделать в приложении, проведя нехитрые манипуляции". Так ли это?

Comment: Вы действительно думаете, что люди, которые знают, как это сделать будут тратить свое время на то, чтобы себе жизней набить в игре?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь уже не покупку сохранить, а сохранить что куплено. И изначально Вы же храните как-то эти жизни, раз после покупки их хотите сохранить. Если так, то и покупать не обязательно, можно просто подправить нужные значения.

Можете хранить в `NSUserDefaults` или в `plist` сохранить, или еще чего. Если хотите как-то защитить - шифруйте значения. Банальное `XOR` шифрование защитит от большинства попыток подправить значения. Если же хотите гарантированно защитить от взлома - без сервера, где будете это хранить/проверять не обойтись.